# Are you student of English literature? Are you a student of English literature OR Are you student in English literature?

Tags: word-usage, questions, question-marks

Hey one question: Which of the questions are right:

> - Are you student of English literature?
> - Are you a student of English literature?
> - Are you student in English literature?

Comment: Before we answer you, you should try to explain us which of the three variants is the correct one and why. It is the rule of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think the possibly correct answers 
could be :

> 1. Are you a student of English literature?
> 2. Are you a student in English literature?

The reason is **"student"** is a countable common noun, so it requires an article 'a' before the word. We usually say **"student of English literature"**, but I have seen expressions such as **"he is a student"** in French.
And also only your second sentence matches one of those correct variations of the usage:

If you use the article "a " beore the word "student" all the sentences are correct.
so only your second sentence is correct.

your first and third sentences are wrong   because you have omitted the article before the word "student"

Comment: We could also say: _Are you the student in English literature?_ (It's a special case, but it would be appropriate when, say, a college is welcoming a new cohort, and everyone knows that only one of the incoming students is studying in the English literature program.)

Comment: Note that while ***in*** *English literature* is grammatical, another meaning is that you are represented as a character (who is a student) in the narrative itself. For instance, it could be a biography or autobiography.

Comment: I should also note that there is only *one* grammatical sentence in the question. The first part of your answer *seems* to contradict the final sentence of your answer. (There is no sentence in the question that reads *Are you a student in English literature?*) I think I know what you had *meant* to say, but you should probably rephrase things slightly. (*I think the only two possibly correct sentences could be:* And also *Only your second sentence matches one of those correct variations; so your first and third sentences are wrong.*)